Getting data from react components
I am new to react and I am trying to make a dummy website for online food ordering. I have a component called items that uses props to add all the food items in the web page.
import { useState } from "react";
import "./items.css"


function Items(props){
    let pizza = 0;
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0)
    const add = () => {
        setQuantity( quantity + 1);
        if (props.name == "Pizza"){
        }
    }
    
    const subtract = () => {
        if( quantity > 0){
            setQuantity( quantity - 1);
            if (props.name == "Pizza"){
                pizza = pizza + 1;
            }
    }
        
    }

    return(
        <div className="Item-card">
            <img src = {props.img} className="Item-image"/>
            <div className="Item-info">
                <h1 className="Item-name">{props.name}</h1>
                <p className="Item-description">
                {props.dis}
                <p className="Item-price"> Price: {props.price}$</p>
                </p>
                <div className="Item-quantity">
                    <button className="button" id = "add" onClick={add}>+</button>
                    <p className="quantity">{quantity}</p>
                    <button className="button" id = "subtract" onClick={subtract}>-</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Items

This is starting to create some problems as I want to get the live value of the quaninty variable from the items component to use it in another component.
I tried to get the value using the document.getElementsbyClass().value but it would not work as there are multiple items with the same class and it just gave the output of undefined.
I was wondering if anyone knew how to handle this problem. I am new to react and programming so I don't know how to deal with it.

It sounds like you may want to "lift state up" to a common parent component, or perhaps a useContext instance, maybe a custom hook, or perhaps some global state management system like Redux.  Basically if multiple components need to share this state then this state can't live in only one of those components, it would need to live somewhere they can all access it.

I agree with David. Prop drilling can get messy. I would recommed useContext or Redux. If you are new to global state management, I would recommend starting with the context API as it is easier to understand. Then, once you get more acquainted with it, then you can move to Redux if you wish.

Lifting state up documentation.

What you want to do is pass the functionality from the parent to the child as props.
You can even declare the add and subtract functions in the parent and and pass that instead, but that is beyond the scope of the question
EDIT:
As mentioned, if the structure of your app becomes deeper, passing down props down multiple nested children becomes problematic, in which case its better to manage your state centrally with a library like redux
import { useState } from "react";
import "./items.css"

function Parent(){
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  
    return <Items quantity={quantity} handleQtyChange={setQuantity}
 }

function Items(props){
    let pizza = 0;
    const add = () => {
        props.handleQtyChange( props.quantity + 1);
        if (props.name == "Pizza"){
        }
    }
    
    const subtract = () => {
        if( props.quantity > 0){
            props.setQuantity( props.quantity - 1);
            if (props.name == "Pizza"){
                pizza = pizza + 1;
            }
    }
        
    }

    return(
        <div className="Item-card">
            <img src = {props.img} className="Item-image"/>
            <div className="Item-info">
                <h1 className="Item-name">{props.name}</h1>
                <p className="Item-description">
                {props.dis}
                <p className="Item-price"> Price: {props.price}$</p>
                </p>
                <div className="Item-quantity">
                    <button className="button" id = "add" onClick={add}>+</button>
                    <p className="quantity">{props.quantity}</p>
                    <button className="button" id = "subtract" onClick={subtract}>-</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Items

